# Why does this attempt to animate my moving sprite work?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm trying to animate the sprite in my game when a button is pressed, but when I press the button, it skips the animation. Its supposed to go one pixel, change sprites, and then go one more pixel and change back. Here is the code

```
//for all
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//my Mario class (cut down a lot)
class Mario {
    // all numbers multiplied by 2 from OG game

    protected Direction dir;
    protected int x, y;
    protected BufferedImage sprite;
    protected String currentSpriteName;

    public Mario() {

        this.x = 54;
        this.y = 808;
        dir = Direction.RIGHT;
        setSprite(MVCE.SMALLSTANDFACERIGHT);
        currentSpriteName = MVCE.SMALLSTANDFACERIGHT;
    }

        public void moveRight(){
      if(this.dir == Direction.LEFT){
        this.dir = Direction.RIGHT;
      }
      else if(this.dir == Direction.RIGHT){
        this.x+=1;
      }
    }

    public void animateMoveRight(){
      if (currentSpriteName.equals(MVCE.SMALLSTANDFACERIGHT)){
        setSprite(MVCE.SMALLWALKFACERIGHT);
      }
      else if (currentSpriteName.equals(MVCE.SMALLWALKFACERIGHT)){
        setSprite(MVCE.SMALLSTANDFACERIGHT);
      }
    }

    public void jump() {
        this.y -= 46;
    }

    public void setSprite(String spriteName) {
        URL spriteAtLoc = MVCE.urlGenerator(spriteName);
        this.sprite = MVCE.generateAndFilter(sprite, spriteAtLoc);
    }

        public void getSprite(){
      System.out.println(this.currentSpriteName);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, null); // DO NOT SET x and y TO ANYTHING,
                                          // this sets 0,0 to top left!!
    }

}
```

```
// my MarioRender class:
class MarioRender extends JLabel {

    protected Mario marioSprite;

    public MarioRender() {
        marioSprite = new Mario();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        marioSprite.paint(g2);
        setBounds(marioSprite.x, marioSprite.y, marioSprite.sprite.getWidth(), marioSprite.sprite.getHeight());
    }

      public void moveMarioRight(){
        marioSprite.moveRight();
        marioSprite.animateMoveRight();
        setLocation(this.marioSprite.getX(), this.marioSprite.getY());
        repaint();
         //this is my attempt to make it animate
        marioSprite.moveRight();
        marioSprite.animateMoveRight();
        setLocation(this.marioSprite.getX(), this.marioSprite.getY());
        repaint();
      }

    public void jumpMario() {
        marioSprite.jump();
        setLocation(this.marioSprite.x, this.marioSprite.y);
        repaint();

    }

}
```

```
// direction class, solely for moving
enum Direction {
    LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

```
// my calling class, which I called MVCE where I make the frame
public class MVCE extends JFrame {

    MarioRender m = new MarioRender();
    JLabel bg;

    public MVCE() {
        bg = new JLabel();
        this.setSize(868, 915);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(bg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bg.setLayout(null);

        bg.add(m);
        m.setBounds(m.marioSprite.x, m.marioSprite.y, m.marioSprite.sprite.getWidth(),
                m.marioSprite.sprite.getHeight());
        KeyListener kl = new MoveListener();
        this.addKeyListener(kl);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static final String SMALLSTANDFACERIGHT = "SmallStandFaceRight.bmp"; // 30
                                                                                // x
                                                                                // 32
    public static final String SMALLJUMPFACERIGHT = "SmallJumpFaceRight.bmp"; // 32
                                                                              // x
                                                                              // 32

    // generate URL
    public static URL urlGenerator(String name) {
        URL u = lookup().lookupClass().getResource(name);
        return u;
    }

    // return image with filtered color
    public static BufferedImage generateAndFilter(BufferedImage b, URL u) {

        try {
            b = ImageIO.read(u);
            int width = b.getWidth();
            int height = b.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            b.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
            for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
                // System.out.println(pixels[i]);
                if (pixels[i] == 0xFFff00fe) {
                    pixels[i] = 0x00ff00fe;
                }
            }
            BufferedImage newSprite = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            newSprite.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
            b = newSprite;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("sprite not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }

    // key listener
    class MoveListener implements KeyListener {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {

            if ((k.getKeyCode() == 39)) {

                m.moveMarioRight();
                 ///THIS IS SUPPOSED TO MOVE HIM 1, change sprite, and automatically move him back, it moves 2 pixels but no animation


            }

            if (k.getKeyCode() == 83) { // S key

                m.marioSprite.setSprite(SMALLJUMPFACERIGHT);
                m.jumpMario();
            }

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MVCE m = new MVCE();
    }

}
```

I tried putting this between the calls to marioMoveRight():

```
    try {
      Thread.sleep(200);                 
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

but it just delays the whole thing. I had also tried using an ActionListener, but I don't know how to make it react only when the key is pushed. as I had it,

I had this class inside of MVCE:

```
class TickListener implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
  m.marioSprite.setSprite(Constants.SMALLWALKFACERIGHT);
  repaint();
  }
}
```

and this at the end of the MVCE constructor:

```
ActionListener ac = new TickListener();
final int DELAY = 1000;
Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, ac);
t.start();
```

but then, the Mario just moves automatically. I do not want to use a sprite sheet for this project, I am trying to do it as [this guy did](https://github.com/jakowskidev/uMario_Jakowski) for SMB1.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems, don't know which one or if any will fix the problem:

1. Don't use a KeyListener. If a component doesn't have focus the component won't receive the event. Instead use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).
2. Don't use "==" to compare Objects. Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method.
3. Don't override paintComponent. A painting method is for painting only. You should not be changing the bounds of the component in the painting method.
4. Do basic debugging (problem solving) before asking a question. A simple System.out.println(...) added to various methods will determine if the code is executing as you expect. Then when you ask a question you can ask a specific question telling us which block of code does not execute as you expect.

Comment: I had a System.out.println between the two calls to marioMoveRight() in the keyListener, and it did print out the different sprite names, but no visual change. Also, if I don't change the bounds in paintComponent, the sprite gets cut off if changed. I did try using equals(), no difference

Comment: @Derry, `if I don't change the bounds in paintComponent, the sprite gets cut off` - once again you should NOT be changing the bounds of a component in a painting method!!!  If fact you should not be doing any custom painting. All you do is add the Icon to the label and the label to the panel. Then you can just change the location of the label on the panel. Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a basic example to get you started.

Comment: Re-asking the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603451/how-can-i-animate-this-sprite-so-when-a-function-is-called-it-switches-sprites?)

Answer (score 0):

You never actually call the method `animateMoveRight()`, and if I understand correcly, that's what's changing the sprite. Also, I doubt that you see the sprite change when calling the same method twice in a row without any delay.
Try putting the `animateMoveRight()` method into the `moveRight()` or the `moveMarioRight()` method and, if neccessary because the animation is too fast, add your delay code back where you had it. Be careful not to let the main thread sleep, as this causes *everything* to freeze, so start another one or use a timer etc.

EDIT: Good timers
I'm not too familiar with the Timer class, so I end up using the Thread variant. There are many tutorials for that out there, just search for "java threads" or "java multithreading". [This](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-multithreading/) is IMO a solid tutorial you can check out.

Comment: even when I did, and put it in marioMoveRight(), it still didn't animate it.